# Kind Demotion (as opposed to Kind Promotion)

Tags: haskell, higher-kinded-types, data-kinds

The [DataKinds](http://downloads.haskell.org/~ghc/latest/docs/html/users_guide/glasgow_exts.html#datatype-promotion) extension promotes "values" (i.e. constructors) into types. For example `True` and `False` become distinct types of kind `Bool`.

What I'd like to do is the opposite, i.e. demote types into values. A function with this signature would be fine:

```
demote :: Proxy (a :: t) -> t
```

I can actually do this, for example for `Bool`:

```
class DemoteBool (a :: Bool) where
  demoteBool :: Proxy (a :: Bool) -> Bool

instance DemoteBool True where
  demoteBool _ = True

instance DemoteBool False where
  demoteBool _ = False
```

However, I'd have to write up instances for any type I want to demote back to it's value. Is there a nicer way of doing this that doesn't involve so much boilerplate?

Comment: The reason you have to do it manually is partiality. Given a type-level `b :: Bool` you don't know for certain that it's either `True` or `False`. It could be a [stuck type](https://typesandkinds.wordpress.com/2015/09/09/what-are-type-families/). A singleton proves that its type isn't stuck. Dependent Haskell will help a bit for this particular case, because `True` and `'True` will be the same thing, but there are still unavoidable problems with partiality.

Comment: @BenjaminHodgson does the existing `TypeInType` help at all here, or is that unrelated?

Comment: It would be fun if strict fields when lifted could not contain stuck types, much like a strict field cannot contain bottom. I just want to be able to scope over `a :: !Bool` and use it in the code :)

Answer (score 13):

That is one of the uses of [`singletons`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/singletons), in particular [`fromSing`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/singletons-2.2/docs/Data-Singletons.html#v:fromSing):

```
ghci> :m +Data.Singletons.Prelude
ghci> :set -XDataKinds
ghci> fromSing (sing :: Sing 'True)
True
```

It still involves a lot of boilerplate, but the package has a lot of it already defined and I believe it provides Template Haskell to let you generate your own more easily (and with less code).

Comment: ps : kind demotion is a particular example of a "comprehension". promotion and demotion are adjoints to each other in a very specific 2-category. many powerful operations could be written that way.